# uploading audio file to facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, audio, file-upload, soundcloud

In my app the user can record an audio file (say of their child's first word).  Is there a way for them to post this on Facebook so that only the people they want to hear it can (privacy settings).  I mean I don't think the user would want to post it on a sight where anyone and everyone could hear it and then link this their facebook page. I have looked around a lot and I see the possibility of Open Graph (which I use to upload a videos from my app) but since there is no direct upload to facebook of audio as I understand it. Each user would have to upload the audio to something like SoundCloud and then link this to Facebook.  I'm not sure SoundCloud is the place for these types of recording.  Does anyone have a better Idea.
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the sound to SoundCloud and keep it private. You will then get a "secret link" to the file which you can post to your friends on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Make a video with no video (black screen) and just audio, and upload it to facebook as video